# resize images not crop

Tags: uploads, images

Looking for a hack to resize images on upload (all forms of image uploads on wordpress) to exact dimensions, but **not to crop.**

I will open a bounty for this question since I believe It can be of help for a lot of people.

The ideal solution must be as a plugin and using the image dimensions already specified on the Media Settings Page (options-media.php / Thumbnail , Medium and Large)

I know the ideal sometimes can't be done, so the closest answer will be the accepted one

Answer (score 5):

## Custom Image Sizes

Resizing without cropping is already part of the core functionality, via [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).

Note the last parameter:

```
<?php add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

The Codex entry describes the `$crop` parameter as follows:

> `$crop`
>
> (boolean) (optional) Crop the image or not. False - Soft proportional crop mode ; True - Hard crop mode.
>      Default: `false`

I prefer to describe the option as **hard-crop** vs. **box-resize**. Hard-crop will crop the image based on the most-restrained dimension, whereas box-resize will simply resize the image, retaining its original dimension proportions.

So, to create a *box-resized* image size, simply define it as follows:

```
add_image_size( 'image-size-name', $width, $height, false );
```

Note that this behavior is the *default* setting. In order to hard-crop, you have to *explicitly specify* `$crop` to be `true`.

## Post Thumbnails

Changing the `post-thumbnail` image size to box-resize is similar; simply use [`set_post_thumbnail_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size), which also has a `$crop` parameter:

```
 <?php set_post_thumbnail_size( $width, $height, $crop ); ?>
```

## Reserved Image Sizes

I'm pretty sure `'medium'` and `'large'` image sizes are already box-resized rather than hard-cropped.